# How can I add an attribute dynamically in Slim lang?

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework, slim-lang

In my Exlir/Phoenix app I'm using slim and I want to add an attribute dynamically:

```
input type="checkbox" <%= if some_condition, do: ~s{checked="checked"} %>
```

However, slim renders this  `checked="checked"` inside the input tag as its content and, more over, escaped.
How can I add  the attribute `checked="checked"` dynamically? Note that this:

```
input type="checkbox" checked="<%= if some_condition, do: ~s{checked} %>"
```

doesn't work for me because I need **either add the whole** checked="checked" to the tag or **nothing** at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a boolean value to the attribute and it'll only output the attribute name if the value is `true`. This should be equivalent to adding `checked="checked"` in HTML5.

```
iex(1)> IO.puts Slime.render("input type=\"checkbox\" checked=some_condition", some_condition: false)
<input type="checkbox">
:ok
iex(2)> IO.puts Slime.render("input type=\"checkbox\" checked=some_condition", some_condition: true)
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

This is also mentioned in [Slime's README](https://github.com/slime-lang/slime#attributes).

Comment: That's a little confusing--there's a _slime_ library for using _slim_ with Elixir. :) For a minute there I thought you'd mistyped.